# How to add delete function in jquery with php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on one jquery script with codeigniter. i get dynamic data in for loop. i want to add crud operations on it. but My view and Edit is working fine.But dont know how to add delete method on it.

```
for(var j=0;j<arrayData.length;j++)
    {
          var country = "";
          var color = "";
          action1 = "VIEW";
          action2 = "EDIT";
          action3 = "DELETE";


            if(arrayData[j].key=="40")
             {
                 country = "UK";                              
                 color = "INDIANRED";
                 check+= '<a class="btn btn-success"  style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/uk_pdf/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+action1+
                              '</a> '+
                                '<a class="btn btn-success"  style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/edit_slips_uk/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+action2 +
                              '</a> ' + '<a class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/delete_slips_uk/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+action3 +
                              '</a> | ';                                      

             }              

    }
```

`arrayData[j].value` in this i am getting my value.`responsible/delete_slips_uk`  I am calling this method to delete my row.
Controller:

```
public function delete_slips_uk()
  {

    $this->load->model('pay_slips_model');
    $result=$this->pay_slips_model->delete_slips_uk($id);        
    if($result==true)
      {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg',"Deleted Successfully");
        redirect('responsible/view_slips_admin_1');
      }
    else
      {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg',"Customer Records Deletion Failed");
        redirect('responsible/view_slips_admin_1');
      }

  }
```

Model:

```
public function delete_slips_uk($id)
                {

                    $this->db->where('id', $id);                   
                    $this->db->delete('uk_new_salary_slip');
                    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
                }
```

I am stuck on delete function. onclick delete it goes to my method it directly goes to else condition with this message `Customer Records Deletion Failed`.I am unable to call post my `arrayData[j].value` from jquery to my controller. please help me with the same. so i can manage to complete my delete operations too.

Comment: Use ajax functions.

Comment: Try doing print_r to the $result variable in your delete_slips_uk() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result=$this->pay_slips_model->delete_slips_uk($id);` expects an `$id` but none is passed causing `delete_slips_uk` to invariably return false.

Revised controller function:

```
public function delete_slips_uk($id=null)
  {

    if (is_null($id)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg',"Missing id!");
        redirect('responsible/view_slips_admin_1');
    }

    $this->load->model('pay_slips_model');
    $result=$this->pay_slips_model->delete_slips_uk($id);        
    if($result==true)
      {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg',"Deleted Successfully");
        redirect('responsible/view_slips_admin_1');
      }
    else
      {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg',"Customer Records Deletion Failed");
        redirect('responsible/view_slips_admin_1');
      }

  }
```

Comment: No problem! In the future you should develop with error reporting on as it would have given you a notice that the variable was missing. Also general troubleshooting suggests that you always check your inputs and outputs at various points ;)